# Highchart - Plot missing DateTime values on xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently plotting points by DateTime and Value using HighCharts.  The points are per minute.  Currently, it's drawing a connecting line between the points as can be seen below.

[image: Graph]

What I'd prefer is to be able to plot a point for each minute inbetween (if there is no value), is this possible with HighCharts? Or would I have to loop through each minute and add it to the data series with a null value?

Comment: Highcharts doesn't create any points, only display what you have passed. If you want null points, then you need to pass them to `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also create an array with every minute in it and then merge that with the values you have ...
or you use the method, that you suggested. I found using an "empty" array easier.

Comment: How did your method differ from having to create a value for each minute?

Comment: i found it easier to create every minute with a "0" value than going thru an already existing array.

Comment: I will wait until anyone has their input and accept your response as answer after a period of time.